# Lie coalgebra with no finite-dimensional subcoalgebras

Tags: lie-algebras, coalgebras

In Walter Michaelis' paper [*Lie Coalgebras*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(80)90056-0), he gives on page 9 an explicit example of a Lie coalgebra which is not the union of its finite-dimensional Lie subcoalgebras. In fact, Michaelis' example has exactly two finite-dimensional Lie subcoalgebras: the zero coalgebra and a certain one-dimensional subcoalgebra.

What I want to know is whether one can do even better: is there a Lie coalgebra $C\neq0$ (over any field) whose only finite-dimensional Lie subcoalgebra is $0$? Ideally, I'd like an explicit example.

Comment: So while (associative) coalgebras are easily seen to be locally finite, from your question it's clear this is not true for Lie coalgebras. Interesting. Very speculatively, the Lie algebra of the Lie group of diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$ is my go-to example of a really 'large' Lie algebra. Maybe it could be useful in some way.

Comment: Yes, this is why I find this result surprising: coassociative coalgebras are always locally finite, as are comodules under them. I'll have to think about whether the Lie algebra you mention could lead to an example. The correct "dual" notion to Lie coalgebras over $\mathbb{R}$ is topological Lie algebras whose underlying topological vector space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^\kappa$ for some cardinal $\kappa$, taking the product topology of the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (or the discrete topology, they give equivalent categories). Does your Lie algebra carry such a topology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the Lie algebra of vector fields on the formal disk, $\mathfrak g=k[[t]]d/dt$, where $k$ is a field of characteristic zero and $k[[t]]$ is the $k$-algebra of formal Taylor power series in the variable $t$.  Then $k[[t]]$ is naturally a topological $k$-algebra with a pro-finite-dimensional ( = pseudocompact = linearly compact) topology, and $\mathfrak g$ is a topological Lie algebra with a pro-finite-dimensional topology.

Consequently, there exists a unique coassociative coalgebra $\mathcal C$ such that $k[[t]]\simeq \mathcal C^*$ as a topological associative algebra, and there exists a unique Lie coalgebra $\mathcal L$ such that $\mathfrak g = \mathcal L^*$ as a topological Lie coalgebra.  Now, of course, $\mathcal C$ is the union of its finite-dimensional subcoalgebras.  However, $\mathcal L$ has no nonzero finite-dimensional Lie subcoalgebras.  In fact, $\mathcal L$ has no nonzero proper Lie subcoalgebras at all.

To prove these assertions about $\mathcal L$, one can translate them back into the topological Lie algebra language, where they become more intuitively clear and can be checked explicitly by hand.  The claims to prove are that the topological Lie algebra $\mathcal g$ has no proper open Lie ideals, and in fact, it does not even have any nonzero proper closed Lie ideals.

The topological Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ has a topological basis $L_{-1}$, $L_0$, $L_1$, $L_2$, $\dots$, where $L_n = t^{n+1}d/dt$.  The commutation relations are $[L_i,L_j]=(j-i)L_{i+j}$.  Suppose $\mathfrak h$ is a nonzero closed Lie ideal in $\mathfrak g$.  Considering the action of $L_0$ in $\mathfrak h$, one shows that $\mathfrak h$ is homogeneous, i.e., if it contains an infinite linear combination of $L_n$ with nonzero coefficient at some $L_j$, then it also contains the element $L_j$ itself.  Now one can use the action of $L_{-1}$ and $L_n$ with $n\gg0$ in $\mathfrak h$ to prove that $\mathfrak h=\mathfrak g$ if $\mathfrak h\ne0$.

Exercises: pinpoint a three-dimensional closed Lie subalgebra in $\mathfrak g$ isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2(k)$, and also an infinite family of pro-nilpotent open Lie subalgebras in $\mathfrak g$ forming a base of the topology of $\mathfrak g$. Realize that these Lie subalgebras are not Lie ideals in $\mathfrak g$.  Conclude that the Lie coalgebra $\mathcal L$ is a union of its finite-dimensional Lie coideals, but these Lie coideals are not Lie subcoalgebras.

Comment: This is great -- in fact what I was originally looking for was phrased on the topological Lie algebra side anyway. Is the final part true in general? I.e. is any Lie coalgebra the union of its finite-dimensional Lie coideals?

Comment: Yes, it is true in general.  In fact, the dual statement holds not only for all linearly compact topological Lie algebras, but even for all locally linearly compact ones.  In the terminology of Beilinson et al., locally linearly compact topological vector spaces (i.e., the ones isomorphic to a direct sum of a discrete vector space and a locally compact one) are called "Tate vector spaces" (reference to John Tate's dissertation, I presume) and locally linearly compact Lie algebras are called "Tate Lie algebras".

Comment: The assertion that any Tate Lie algebra has a topology base of open Lie subalgebras is a simple lemma due to Beilinson or Beilinson and Drinfeld.  It can be found in their joint book "Chiral Algebras", Section 3.8.17, pages 233-234, footnote 70.  The same lemma with the same sketch of proof can be also found in Beilinson's paper "Remarks on topological algebras", Moscow Math. Journ. 8 #1 (2008), Section 1.4, page 6, footnote 4.

Comment: Ah, interesting! I'd not met this notion of linearly compact topological vector spaces before -- I was used to thinking of these kinds of Lie algebras inside the pro-category of finite-dimensional vector spaces. These two categories (pro-finite-dimensional vector spaces and linearly compact topological vector spaces) are equivalent, but the latter gives a more concrete way of thinking about the same objects.